# How to set DATABASE_URL environment variable for Postgres Mac terminal?

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, sqlalchemy, environment-variables

I am using postgres on Mac. I have a database up and running. I want to use it with Flask (SQL Alchemy) but the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable didn't create itself (I think it's supposed to do that). Here is the code I tried running:

```
import os
print(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
```

And there's no output. How can I set the variable (if I need to set it up manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to do that manually. So, within your terminal do this:

```
% cd
% nano .bash_profile
```

It will open a file 'bash_profile' in editor in your terminal. 
And in there you can set environmental variables like:

```
export DATABASE_URL="YOUR DATABASE URL"
```

Check this video out for more info: https://youtu.be/5iWhQWVXosU

Comment: How can I find out what my URL is in the first place?

Comment: Should be something like this: "postgresql://your_username:your_password@postgresql:5432/database_name"