# How do I set path to database in sql alchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, environment-variables, cs50

I am doing cs50 webdev course and I have got problem in this line of application.py

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
```

How do I set up SQL Alchemy to run locally?

Comment: What is the url of your database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768498/connecting-to-database-using-sqlalchemy-using-database-url, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61901732/how-to-set-database-url-environment-variable-for-postgres-mac-terminal, https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/34605/cant-create-table-from-postgresql-through-sqlalchemy-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to setup db locally to start database server,
Lets assume you have postgreSQL db then the code would be :

```
local_db_url = 'postgres://db_username:db_password@localhost/db_name'
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", local_db_url))
```

if DATABASE_URL is not found in the environment variables it will use the default as 'local_db_url'

Comment: Thank you very much. 'postgres://db_username:db_password@localhost/db_name' is it the path to my database? Sorry I am new to this. Will it work for local database?

Comment: you will have to replace it with your local database connection parameters in same format.

Comment: what am I supposed to enter as last parameter? Is it table name or what? How am I supposed to know which database it is? Again thank you very much your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes that is table name. You have done database setup on your local? If not then you will have to do it first and then you will have all the above details.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved that issue. The problem was in this line: engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")) , os.getenv was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts to retrieve an environment variable named `DATABASE_URL`.

In order to use environment variables, you need to set their value before running your code, or have some method of injecting it into your code.

if you're running it via a terminal, then you can run:

`export DATABASE_URL=<your db url goes here>`

In case you're running it via an IDE, most IDE's will allow you configuring environment variables that are injected before the IDE executes your code.

I'm adding on how to do it in some of the most common ones, but if it's not one of the below, you can always search on how to set environment variables in your IDE.

`PyCharm` - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

`Visual Studio Code` - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_configure-environment-of-terminal-sessions